# Loop to create multiple Dataframes from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following list:

`teams = ['BOS_2008', 'CLE_2008', 'LAC_2008',...]`

I want to convert each of the name in the list to be its own stand alone dataframe.  My best guess that I will need to create some sort of loop.  I have seen similar questions on here but none of the answers work for my situation.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What kind of dataframe you want to create? And how you want to name them?

Comment: They will be Python dataframes.  The names will be the same as the items in the list (BOS_2008, CLE_2008, LAC_2008...).  I am open to any suggestions on how to build a loop to create multiple individually named dataframes.

Comment: Best way probably would be to create a dictionary, which keys are the names inside teams and all of these keys contains a dataframe such as list. That way you would have correctly named dataframes and they would be easily modified.

Comment: So @Jerel you want to create dataframes whose names would the list values, and each of the created dataframes would contain just one row and one column, which would be again same as the dataframe name? Just wondering what is the purpose of this in an atempt to find out the real requirement that you are trying to work on.

Answer (score 0):

So @Jerel you want to create dataframes whose names would be the list values, and each of the created dataframes would contain just one row and one column, which would be again same as the dataframe name?

As per your comment if that is exactly what you want (even though I am not sure what good would that be for anything), here is one way how you can achieve it:

```
import pandas as pd

teams = ['BOS_2008', 'CLE_2008', 'LAC_2008']
outputdict = dict()

for team in teams:
    outputdict[team] = pd.DataFrame(team, index=[0], columns=['Value'])

for index, df in outputdict.items():
    print(df)
```